# To create custom attribute on input html element in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, custom-attribute

I want to create a custom attribute input-format
I can assign two values to the attribute that would enable me to clean the input string or to trim input string.

Like below:

For value *clean*:

Trying to achieve declaring as below

```
    <input
         type="text"
         placeholder="enter text with illegal characters"
         value.bind="dirtyString"
         input-format= "format : clean"
    />
```

The above should result me with the below embedded into the input element:

```
     <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="enter text with illegal characters"
            value.bind="dirtyString | cleanString & updateTrigger:'blur'"
            keypress.delegate="keypress($event)"
      />
```

Similarly for *trim*

```
    <input
         type="text"
         placeholder="enter your name"
         value.bind="Name"
         input-format= "format : trim"
     />
```

should result in:

```
    <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="enter your name"
        value.bind="Name | trimString & updateTrigger:'blur'"
    />
```

where cleanString, trimString, are value converters and  keypress function  which are already declared as needed. I need help with creating custom attribute as I am not sure of getting the current *value* bound to an html input element and also reassigning that to have all the above value converters and a function.

Can anyone please help me on achieving this? Appreciate your input and help.

This is where I stand:

```
import * as au from "aurelia-framework";

@au.autoinject
@au.customAttribute("input-format")
export class InputFormat {
  constructor(element: Element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  @au.bindable
  format: string;
  formatChanged(name: string, newValue: string, oldValue: string) {
    // need to have case statements 
    switch(name){
        case 'clean':
          // to assign the relevant value converter and the 'value' is to be passed into
          // this assigment should result something like below
          // <input
          // type="text"
          // value.bind="Name | cleanString & updateTrigger:'blur'"
          // keypress.delegate="keypress($event)"
         //  >
          break;
        case 'trim':
          // to assign the relevant value converter the 'value' is to be passed into
          // <input
          // type="text"
          // value.bind="Name | trimString"          
         //  >
          break;
        default:
          // to leave the assigment as is 
          break;
      }

  }
  // the select list
  element: Element;
  val: any;
}
```

here is the link where I am trying to put things together:
[sand box link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/custom-attribute-for-clean-string-xm531)

Comment: What you want to do is pretty advanced stuff. I'd venture to say that a Custom Element would be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: @AshleyGrant yeah you are absolutely right. So I went on to use aurelia-inputmask, which pretty much solved my issues. Had to get around creating another value converter for trim and also had to handle the initialization of input fields with another value converter as it would show up undefined on first load. So now the solution can be applied across application, but it looks dirty to have everything on the html input elements though.